# Error with NSNumber

Tags: ios7

I am new to the iOS development and I was trying to do something mentioned below and it was giving me an error:

> Implicit conversion of an objective c pointer to 'NSInteger*(aka int*) is disallowed with ARC.

In the below code, `seg_pressed` is a property of segmented control.

```
NSInteger *choice =[NSNumber numberWithInt:_seg_pressed.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger is a raw type (much like C's "`int`" or "`char`").  You should declare "`*choice`" as a "`NSNumber *`" object.

E.G.:

```
NSNumber *choice = [NSNumber numberWithInt:_seg_pressed.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

NSNumber is an Objective-C object, whereas NSInteger ultimately turns into a "`long`".  Which can be different depending on which platform/architecture you're running under.  As [Apple's Foundation data types doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) says:

> When building 32-bit applications, NSInteger is a 32-bit integer. A
>   64-bit application treats NSInteger as a 64-bit integer.